# How to filter datagridview using two combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview and two combobox(cboYear & cboSection). I have successfully filtered the datagridview using the first combobox, now I want to know how to filter the filtered datagridview using the second combobox(Show all students in the specific year and section). I have already searched some but I don't understand how it works.

Here is my code for filtering using the first cbo.

```
//Filter using combobox
    private void LoadYearSection()
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (cboYear.Text == "All Students")
        {
            guna2DataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            cn.Open();
            cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT s.studentID, s.studentNo, s.Lname, s.Fname, s.MI, s.gender, s.yearLevel, s.section, s.studImage, g.name, g.contactNo, g.address FROM Student s INNER JOIN Guardian g ON g.studentNo = s.studentNo WHERE g.studentNo = s.studentNo AND s.isActive = 'true'", cn);
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                i += 1;
                guna2DataGridView1.Rows.Add(i, dr["studentID"].ToString(), dr["studentNo"].ToString(), dr["Lname"].ToString(), dr["Fname"].ToString(), dr["MI"].ToString(), dr["gender"].ToString(), dr["yearLevel"].ToString(), dr["section"].ToString(), dr["name"].ToString(), dr["contactNo"].ToString(), dr["address"].ToString(), dr["studImage"]);
            }
            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            guna2DataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            cn.Open();
            cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT s.studentID, s.studentNo, s.Lname, s.Fname, s.MI, s.gender, s.yearLevel, s.section, s.studImage, g.name, g.contactNo, g.address FROM Student s INNER JOIN Guardian g ON g.studentNo = s.studentNo WHERE g.studentNo = s.studentNo AND s.isActive = 'true' AND s.yearLevel LIKE @yearLevel", cn);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yearLevel", cboYear.Text);
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                i += 1;
                guna2DataGridView1.Rows.Add(i, dr["studentID"].ToString(), dr["studentNo"].ToString(), dr["Lname"].ToString(), dr["Fname"].ToString(), dr["MI"].ToString(), dr["gender"].ToString(), dr["yearLevel"].ToString(), dr["section"].ToString(), dr["name"].ToString(), dr["contactNo"].ToString(), dr["address"].ToString(), dr["studImage"]);
            }
            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would think it may be a better approach to “query” for all the data “once” and put it in a `DataSet/DataTable` then filter the data from the `DataSet/DataTable` as opposed to re-querying the DB every time the user changes a combo box value. Also, you could/should use them as a `DataSource` to the grid, Manually adding the rows from a `DataTable` as the posted code does is unnecessary and creates more work for you.

Answer (score 0):

All this would require is to alter the query to include the section. I don't know the data, but could look something like:

```
private void LoadYearSection()
{
    int i = 0;
    string yearClause = string.Empty;
    string sectionClause = string.Empty;
    
    if (cboYear.Text != "All Students")
    {
        yearClause = "AND s.yearLevel = @yearLevel";
    }
    if (cboSection.Text != "All Students")
    {
        sectionClause = "AND s.section = @section"
    }

    guna2DataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    cn.Open();
    cm = new SqlCommand($@"SELECT s.studentID, s.studentNo, s.Lname, s.Fname, s.MI, s.gender, s.yearLevel, s.section, s.studImage, g.name, g.contactNo, g.address 
    FROM Student s 
    INNER JOIN Guardian g ON g.studentNo = s.studentNo 
    WHERE g.studentNo = s.studentNo AND s.isActive = 'true' {yearClause} {sectionClause}", cn);

    if (cboYear.Text != "All Students")
    {
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yearLevel", cboYear.Text);
    }
    if (cboSection.Text != "All Students")
    {
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@section", cboSection.Text);
    }
    
    dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        i += 1;
        guna2DataGridView1.Rows.Add(i, dr["studentID"].ToString(), dr["studentNo"].ToString(), dr["Lname"].ToString(), dr["Fname"].ToString(), dr["MI"].ToString(), dr["gender"].ToString(), dr["yearLevel"].ToString(), dr["section"].ToString(), dr["name"].ToString(), dr["contactNo"].ToString(), dr["address"].ToString(), dr["studImage"]);
    }
    dr.Close();
    cn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Hello, this still doesn't work. Nothing is showing in my datagridview

Answer (score 0):

Just add more parameters, it is not rocket science. But I have few hints for you

- DRY - Don't repeat yourself. Copy&paste piece of your code in your program if usually a bad thing.
- dispose what is disposable, use `using`
- you do not need `g.studentNo = s.studentNo` in `WHERE`, you already have in `ON` condition
- avoid AddWithValue, define type explicitly

  ```
    guna2DataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
    try
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (var cm = new SqlCommand())
        {
            StringBuilder commandText = new StringBuilder(
                @"SELECT s.studentID, s.studentNo, s.Lname, s.Fname, s.MI, s.gender, 
                         s.yearLevel, s.section, s.studImage, g.name, g.contactNo, g.address
                  FROM Student s
                  INNER JOIN Guardian g ON g.studentNo = s.studentNo
                  WHERE 1=1");

            if (onlyActive)
            {
                commandText.Append(" AND s.isActive = 'true'");
            }
            if (cboYear.Text != "All Students")
            {
                commandText.Append(" AND s.yearLevel LIKE @yearLevel");
                cm.Parameters.Add("@yearLevel", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 400).Value = cboYear.Text;
            }
            // add any number of conditions

            cm.Connection = cn;
            cm.CommandText = commandText.ToString();
            using (var dr = cm.ExecuteReader())
            {
                int i = 0;
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    guna2DataGridView1.Rows.Add(++i,
                        dr["studentID"].ToString(), 
                        dr["studentNo"].ToString(), 
                        dr["Lname"].ToString(), 
                        dr["Fname"].ToString(), 
                        dr["MI"].ToString(), 
                        dr["gender"].ToString(), 
                        dr["yearLevel"].ToString(), 
                        dr["section"].ToString(),
                        dr["name"].ToString(), 
                        dr["contactNo"].ToString(), 
                        dr["address"].ToString(), 
                        dr["studImage"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        cn.Close();
    }
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much but this just also only filtered the data using the first combobox sir

Comment: You should be able to implement it now on the marked place.